# Counters for changes in column

Tags: python, pandas

How would I go about creating two counters in columns as a third column changes? For example, I have the below Flag, and I want to start counting in one column, then change its value to nan when Flag changes, and count in the other column, and continue counting back and forth in this manner.

```
Flag    Counter1    Counter2
   0           1         nan
   0           1         nan
   0           1         nan
   1         nan           1
   1         nan           1
   1         nan           1
   0           2         nan
   1         nan           2
```

Comment: Have you tried anything that didn't work?

Comment: Well, I'm thinking a pandas-centric answer would probably combine possibly diff(), shift(), and cumsum(), but I'm not really sure how to combine them to get what I would like.

I've run a simple for loop to do it, but I'm wondering if there's something more efficient.

Comment: For a start, it would be good to make clear, what your input is. Does the df with three columns already exist or is `flag` a list or a `numpy` array or what?

Comment: Flag exists as a column in a dataframe, the counters are just the results I'd like to see as added columns.

Comment: I figured out that `df['Count'] = abs(df['Flag'].diff()).cumsum()` would get me a count of all changes, but is there a simlar way to count changes from 0 to 1 and 1 to 0 separately in two separate columns?

Comment: Nice. Can you do this after filtering for `df['Flag']  == 0`? Of course, you have to fill the first element with 0 and add 1 to the whole column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
#create consecutives groups
a = df['Flag'].ne(df['Flag'].shift()).cumsum()

m1 = df['Flag'] == 1
m2 = df['Flag'] == 0
#get Trues for edge rows
m3 = ~a.duplicated()

m4 = m3 & m1
m5 = m3 & m2

#add NaNs or count by cumulative sum
df['Counter2'] =  np.where(m2, np.nan, m4.cumsum())
df['Counter1'] =  np.where(m1, np.nan, m5.cumsum())
print (df)
   Flag  Counter1  Counter2
0     0       1.0       NaN
1     0       1.0       NaN
2     0       1.0       NaN
3     1       NaN       1.0
4     1       NaN       1.0
5     1       NaN       1.0
6     0       2.0       NaN
7     1       NaN       2.0
```

Comment: pls cehck https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185389/droping-rows-when-some-of-the-columns-have-value-0-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: This works beautifully, and it's super fast. Thanks @jezrael